# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/obj' in Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I am working with YOLOv3 and I customize the cfg file using my own dataset. End the YOLOv3 object detection project I faced an error and that is **File Not Find Error** type.
**Below the upload the script.py script to cloud VM from Google Drive,**

```
!cp /mydrive/custommodel/script.py ./

!ls

9k.tree     eagle.jpg    imagenet.labels.list      obj.names         script.py
coco9k.map  giraffe.jpg  imagenet.shortnames.list  openimages.names  voc.names
coco.names  goal.txt     labels            person.jpg
dog.jpg     horses.jpg   obj.data          scream.jpg
```

**script.py** file is successfully uploaded.

**Now, I faced an error in below, please concern here,**

```
!python script.py
```

**after run the above code, error is occurred,**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
    os.chdir(os.path.join("data", "obj"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/obj'
```

**Note:** For running the above code, It will create a train.txt file where will stored all of own dataset in required file then I can run it for training. But is showed an error and that is file directory.

Comment: Is the path `'data/obj'` relative to the directory you show the listing of above?  If so, I don't see a `data` directory in there.  Your script expects to find a directory named `data` in the current working directory, and expect to find a `obj` directory inside that directory.  Do you know where these directories are supposed to be found?